# Json and Ext JS 3.4 using ASP.NET and SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, sql-server-2008, extjs

I've a table called movie_genres:

| genre_id  |  genre_name  |

A combobox (Ext js) that I will populate with those genres from the database

```
...
/* Remote data store */
    var movie_genres = new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            fields: ['genre_id', 'genre_name'],
            root: 'rows'
        }),
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: '../GenresWebService.asmx/GetGenres'
        })
    });



var movie_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    url: 'movie-form-submit.aspx',
    renderTo: 'myform',
    frame: true,
    title: 'Movie Information Form',
    width: 400,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        hiddenName: 'genre',
        fieldLabel: 'Genre',
        mode: 'remote',
        store: movie_genres,
        displayField: 'genre_name',
        valueField: 'genre_id'
    },
    ...
```

I'm using a WebService in ASP.NET to fetch the genres from the database in a json formatted string.

```
public class GenresWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetGenres()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            String sql = "SELECT genre_id, genre_name FROM movie_genres";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            DataSet genres = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(genres, "movie_genres");


            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = jss.Serialize(genres);
            con.Close();

            return "{rows:" + json + "}";
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens, my combobox is empty, got no genres, no errors, no response, nothing...
Any ideas, what's wrong with my code?

Thank you

**EDIT**
I added `autoLoad: true` to the store definition as @allie mentioned and now I get an error on firebug says:

```
Get http://localhost:12345/GenresWebService.asmx/GetGenres?_dc=1344964138589 500 Internal Server Error 17 ms.
```

The response on firebug explains the error as follows:

System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.
   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)....

I've tried to debug the GenresWebService and I've got the error above on this line:

```
string json = jss.Serialize(genres);
```

I don't know wat it means actually :(

Comment: Just to clarify, is the **response** empty? What status code is it returning with?

Comment: Can you post the response you get after calling your webservice?

Comment: I'm using firebug to check it out, but no response.
That's what I meant by "response empty"!!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no response, there is also no request?

Does it help if you add **autoLoad:true** to the store definition ?

Comment: I've edited my question after adding autoLoad:true as you said, please let met know if you know what to do next.